# Erase Windows Vista to Install Ubuntu

Tags: windows-vista

new here. I have an old E-machine which as Windows Vista on it and I want to erase the Windows Vista, and install Ubuntu on it instead, but I am not sure where to start. Can I first install Ubuntu, and THEN erase Windows Vista, or is there a more sure method? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

When installing Ubuntu the install wizard asks you, if you want to install Ubuntu beside windows, or if you want to use the whole drive. Simply choose to use the whole drive and Windows gets erased automatically!

Comment: I tried to open the .iso file but the message came up asking me if I wanted to find the correct program to open it. I tried using rufus too, but underneath each section, there were no options. If it matters, I don't have it hooked up to the internet.